# Categories for layered navigation in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm looking to enhance the layered navigation in Magento.

Presently, attributes that are used in layered navigation can't be grouped, meaning if you have several attributes that are logically in one group (i.e. attributes "height", "width" & "depth" which are "Dimensions", and "color" and "texture" belong in an "Appearance" section).

I think this would enhance the usability and navigation for users.

Before I go ahead and begin developing a module for this, I was wondering if anyone came across something like this for magento, and if not, do you have any tips how this should be done?

Joseph

Comment: Um, just change the view and you can have them separately grouped. The file is catalog/layer/view.phtml.

Comment: I guess I can do that. But not ideal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a module for this.  Here are the changes I made:

MyName/Navigation/Catalog/Model/Layer.php:

```
class MyName_Navigation_Catalog_Model_Layer extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer {
    public function getFilterableAttributes()
    {
        $setIds = $this->_getSetIds();
        if (!$setIds) {
            return array();
        }

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
            ->setItemObjectClass('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');

        $collection->addSetInfo(true);

        $collection->getSelect()->distinct(true);
        $collection
            ->setAttributeSetFilter($setIds)
            ->addStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->setOrder('position', 'ASC');

        $collection = $this->_prepareAttributeCollection($collection);
        $collection->load();

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

I'm just rewriting the overridden function from Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer with that addition of the line:

```
        $collection->addSetInfo(true);
```

This ensures that the group data will be loaded when I need it.

The next two changes just allow you to access the data.

MyName/Navigation/Catalog/Model/Layer/Attribute.php:

```
class MyName_Navigation_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute {

    public function getGroupName($setId = 4) {       
        $attribute = $this->getAttributeModel();
        $group_id = $attribute->getData('attribute_set_info/' . $setId . '/group_id');
        $group = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')->load($group_id);
        $group_name = $group->getData('attribute_group_name');

        return $group_name;
    }

}
```

MyName/Navigation/Catalog/Model/Layer/Item.php:

```
class MyName_Navigation_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Item extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Item {
    public function getGroupName()
    {
        return $this->getFilter()->getGroupName();
    }
}
```

MyName/Navigation/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php:

```
class MyName_Navigation_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Attribute extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Attribute {
    public function getGroupName() {
        return $this->_filter->getGroupName();
    }
}
```

Tell magento to use my module and not the core files.
MyName/Navigation/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <MyName_Navigation>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyName_Navigation>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <layer_filter_attribute>MyName_Navigation_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Attribute</layer_filter_attribute>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <layer>MyName_Navigation_Catalog_Model_Layer</layer>
                    <layer_filter_attribute>MyName_Navigation_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute</layer_filter_attribute>
                    <layer_filter_item>MyName_Navigation_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Item</layer_filter_item>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Now you can call

```
$_item->getGroupName();
```

from your template file:  template/catalog/layer/filter.php 
or

$_filter->getGroupName();
from your template file: template/catalog/layer/view.php 
and Group/Sort the attributes from there.

Comment: Looks great. And for this to work all I would need to do is put the attribute in the correct attribute group....

Comment: This is not quite what I was looking for, because the grouping happens in the $_item. -- which is a option for a specific attribute. I need this to happen higher up, ie before we loop through the attributes, we should first loop through the attribute groups, and if there are filterable attributes in that group, print the group name, and then loop through the attributes.

Comment: I needed to access the group info at the filter level so I hacked that together and edited my answer.  Hopefully this fits your bill, and if not I hope it at leasts points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The code for the filtered navigation has been on the Magento forums for a long time, it still works in the most recent versions:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/5500/

This may provide what you need to customise the appearance of the filtered navigation to suit your needs.

You can also define in your attribute the sort order in the layered navigation. Rather than use '1, 2, 3' go for '100, 200, 300' so that later on you can define - say - 'width' to 210, etc. and slot the attributes in to the sort order you need.

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. I guess I wasn't clear enough. I'm looking to create another header (the attribute group) in the layered navigation block, which will break up the attributes into categories.